# joins condition on active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, active-record-query

I have two Models

```
Order has_many State(s)
State belongs_to Order
a State has an attribute named 'kind'
```

I'm trying to express the following query with active record: 'all the orders that have current_state.kind = :something',

the current_state is the last created state for an order.

I also also add in the model :current_state as a has_one association:

```
has_one :current_state, -> { order('created_at DESC').limit(1) }, class_name: 'State'
```

but it doesn't help

Comment: What error do you get with this solution?

Comment: I don't get any error but I'm not able to express the query all Orders where 'current_order.kind' is 'something'

Comment: `Order.joins(:states).where(states: { kind: 'something' })` should do the trick ;) (I dont know why @MarekLipka erased his answer though...)

Comment: nope, that doesn't express the fact that "the most recent order must be of kind something' I might have an order with 3 states A B C, this must return the order if and only if C.kind = something

Comment: @MrYoshiji that's exactly why I erased my answer.

Comment: `Order.joins(:states).where(states: { kind: 'something' }).order('orders.created_at DESC')`

Comment: no, that doesn't work either because if I have an order with state A and B (where A.kind = something, B.kind != something) it returns the order, and it shouldn't

Comment: Order.joins(:states).where(states: { kind: 'something', id: #{current_state.id} } )

Comment: do you mean: .where(states: { kind: 'something', id: 'current_state.id' } )?

Comment: uhm, no it doesn't work :(

Comment: I guess we first have to agree what is "good enough". I am not fluent enough in ActiveRecord to express it exactly, but if I had to do it in SQL it would probably look like

    `select * from Orders o
      join states s on ( s.order_id=o.id)
     where s.created_at =
            (select max(created_at) from states s2
              where s2.order_id = o.id)
       AND s.kind = 'something';`

don't you think? (too bad indentation does not work in comments ...)

Comment: I managed to do it with in SQL with a nested query (as u suggested) but I would like to have this query expressed with active record. I wander if it's even possibile

Comment: Of course the above is not perfect if two states may be `created_at` the same second, but it will do in most cases. As far as I know `.id`is not guaranteed to increase monotonically, no? But we could use a combination of the two. Now: how do we do this in AREL?

Comment: As it seems this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267772/correlated-subquery-in-activerecord-or-squeel) has not seen an answer yet ... (sorry, could not get the link inline)

Answer (score 0):

this is the best solution I've found so far

```
Order.joins(:states).where("states.id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM states GROUP BY order_id)").where("states.kind"=>"checkedin")
```